# What does lib folder contain in my ubuntu 16.04 ec2 instance?

Tags: 16.04, amazon-ec2

I am running short of space in my ec2 instance due to backups that I am taking. So I checked other places where I could reduce the space and found a lib folder in the root directory which takes 511 MB. So I checked it contents and found these files

```
51M ./4.4.0-62-generic
42M ./4.4.0-45-generic
53M ./4.4.0-64-generic
51M ./4.4.0-59-generic
42M ./4.4.0-36-generic
53M ./4.4.0-63-generic
42M ./4.4.0-42-generic
44M ./4.4.0-51-generic
51M ./4.4.0-57-generic
44M ./4.4.0-53-generic
42M ./4.4.0-47-generic
511M    .
```

Are these files important? What do they contain? and can I delete them?

Answer (score 2):

Package: linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic (4.4.0-36.55) [security]
Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

So if these files are taking too much space. Just a simple `sudo apt-get autoremove` should remove these unnecessary files.

Now to answer the question are these files important? I don't think so. They are image files, probably for purpose of some sort of restoration. Some ubuntu expert can throw more light on them, these packages don't have much detail about them [on their page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kernel/linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic)